# display formview on gridview row selected

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

On click of the selected row from the gridview I want to display the formview. It is working properly with the help of commandfield whereas i want it to be displayed when i select the row.

Also I want when the formview to be displayed in a new window. I have used update panel for both the gridview and the formview but still when i click on the select button the gridview and the formview are displayed on the same page.
The code for reference

http://pastebin.com/qnQnAEUy

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think at all that the FormView is shown in a new window? You could put it into a [`ModalPopupExtender`](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx) that you could show from the GridView's [`SelectedIndexChangedEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedindexchanged.aspx). http://lekshmi.org/2008/10/31/modalpopupextender-example-for-editing-rows-in-a-gridview/

Comment: I have used the gridview selectedindexchangedevent but it is displaying the formview below the gridview. I have used update panel for the same so that when a row is selected only the formview is displayed and not the gridview. I don't want to use the popup

Comment: It's still unclear what you want. The user selects one row, the FormView should show the corresponding details but the GridView should be invisible then? Then simply switch the `Visible` property of the GridView and FormView.

Comment: Ok thanks that works fine any ideas regarding my first question

Comment: What _is_ your first question?

Comment: On click of the selected row from the gridview I want to display the formview. It is working properly with the help of commandfield select button but i want it to be displayed when i select the row.

Comment: That is not a question and it's also not clear what's not working as expected. _"It is working properly with the help of commandfield select button"_ So what is not working properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with the help of

http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/view9FC28EE6-ACB0-4F51-BFE4-38B0B10134D5.htm.

Thanks all